# Python Multi-index errors with multiplying

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data frame, and I am trying to multiply across a multi-index.

df1=raw is multi-index

df2=caps

```
#df1 
import pandas as pd

# Create the multi-index
index_values = [('SUB1', 'INV001', 'InverterA_Input1'), ('SUB1', 'INV002', 'InverterA_Input1'), ('SUB1', 'INV0023', 'InverterA_Input1')]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_values, names=['Substation', 'DeviceID', 'Input'])

# Create the DataFrame with the multi-index columns
data = [[112, 74.22, 83.15], [113.59, 79.94, 83.9]]  # Example data for the DataFrame
raw = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=multi_index)
```

And

```
#df2
import pandas as pd

# Create the data for the DataFrame
data = [
    ['SUB1', 'INV001', 'Input1', 'INV001A', 110],
    ['SUB1', 'INV001', 'Input1', 'INV001A', 115],
    ['SUB1', 'INV001', 'Input1', 'INV001A', 118]
]

# Create the DataFrame
caps = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Substation', 'DeviceID', 'Input', 'AnalysisGroup', 'Capacity'])
```

I am trying to multiply caps `caps["Capacity"].max() / caps["Capacity"]` across raw using this code:

```
scaled = raw.multiply(
            caps["Capacity"].max() / caps["Capacity"], axis=1
        ).copy  

#I keep getting errors: ValueError: multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex
```

I also tried:

```
multiplied = raw.groupby(level=[0, 1]).apply(lambda group: group.multiply(group['Capacity'].max() / group['Capacity']))      

# I get errors ValueError: multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex
```

And get errors ValueError: multiple levels only valid with MultiIndex

What is the best way to do the above across a non-unique multi-index!

Comment: What is your expected output???

Comment: I am trying to create a new multi-index data frame where I use the values in data frame caps ```caps["Capacity"].max() / caps["Capacity"]``` to multiply across all values in data frame raw

Comment: I still don't follow. Indexes don't match. Please share your expected output and make sure the dataframes you created are correct.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is ambiguous, but I imagine this might be:

```
scaled = caps.set_index(['Substation', 'DeviceID', 'Input'])['Capacity'].pipe(lambda s: s.max()/s)

raw.mul(scaled, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
Substation             SUB1                                                   
DeviceID             INV001           INV002          INV0023           INV003
Input      InverterA_Input1 InverterA_Input1 InverterA_Input1 InverterA_Input1
0                  1.072727         2.052174              NaN              NaN
1                  4.290909         5.130435              NaN              NaN
```

Used inputs (slightly modified):

```
import pandas as pd

index_values = [('SUB1', 'INV001', 'InverterA_Input1'), ('SUB1', 'INV002', 'InverterA_Input1'), ('SUB1', 'INV0023', 'InverterA_Input1')]
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_values, names=['Substation', 'DeviceID', 'Input'])

data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]  # Example data for the DataFrame
raw = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=multi_index)

data = [
    ['SUB1', 'INV001', 'InverterA_Input1', 110],
    ['SUB1', 'INV002', 'InverterA_Input1', 115],
    ['SUB1', 'INV003', 'InverterA_Input1', 118]
]

caps = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Substation', 'DeviceID', 'Input', 'Capacity'])
```

Comment: I edited the question to fix missing data.   I am trying to create a new multi-index data frame where I use the values in data frame caps caps["Capacity"].max() / caps["Capacity"] to multiply across all values in data frame raw

Comment: @BB.squared in your example, the indices don't match. InverterA_Input1 and Input_1 won't match. Also in `caps` you have 3 different values for the same combination of Substation/DeviceID/Input

Comment: I think that is my problem. I will upload a working example, as I am trying to correct someone else's code.